# Building an autoencoder for tabular data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoder

I'm trying to build an autoencoder for a tabular dataset a la this tutorial: https://pierpaolo28.github.io/blog/blog29/. I used the housing prices dataset. I imputed the missing values, normalized and dummified the data but I get terrible loss results when training my autoencoder.

Here's the autoencoder code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers

input_dim = X.shape[1]
encoding_dim = 30

input_layer = Input(shape=(input_dim, ))

encoder = Dense(int(input_dim / 2), activation="tanh", 
                activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(10e-5))(input_layer)
encoder = Dense(int(input_dim / 2), activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))(encoder)
encoder = Dense(int(input_dim / 4), activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))(encoder)
encoder = Dense(int(input_dim / 4), activation="tanh")(encoder)
encoder = Dense(encoding_dim, activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))(encoder) # the bottleneck layer

decoder = Dense(int(input_dim / 4), activation="tanh")(encoder)
decoder = Dense(int(input_dim / 4), activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))(decoder)
decoder = Dense(int(input_dim / 2), activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))(decoder)
decoder = Dense(int(input_dim / 2), activation='tanh')(decoder)

output_layer = Dense(input_dim, activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))(decoder)

autoencoder = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

from sklearn import metrics
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', 
                    loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsolutePercentageError(),
                    metrics = ["mse", "mae" ])

history = autoencoder.fit (X_train, X_train,
                    epochs=100,
                    batch_size=3000,
                    shuffle=True,
                    validation_data=(X_test, X_test),
                    verbose=1).history
```

And here are three first and three last training epochs:

```
Epoch 1/100
2/3 [===================>..........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 150489.0781 - mse: 0.1862 - mae: 0.1872WARNING:tensorflow:Callbacks method `on_train_batch_end` is slow compared to the batch time (batch time: 0.0110s vs `on_train_batch_end` time: 0.8014s). Check your callbacks.
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: model.z1\assets
3/3 [==============================] - 3s 976ms/step - loss: 144704.7656 - mse: 0.1862 - mae: 0.1872 - val_loss: 52245.2031 - val_mse: 0.1862 - val_mae: 0.1871
Epoch 2/100
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 52511.4844 - mse: 0.1862 - mae: 0.1871 - val_loss: 61640.7930 - val_mse: 0.1861 - val_mae: 0.1871
Epoch 3/100
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 56115.3867 - mse: 0.1861 - mae: 0.1871 - val_loss: 80056.0391 - val_mse: 0.1861 - val_mae: 0.1871
...
Epoch 97/100
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 42958.1523 - mse: 0.1824 - mae: 0.1845 - val_loss: 42867.2852 - val_mse: 0.1824 - val_mae: 0.1845
Epoch 98/100
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 44007.1992 - mse: 0.1824 - mae: 0.1845 - val_loss: 46307.1250 - val_mse: 0.1824 - val_mae: 0.1845
Epoch 99/100
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 45433.2266 - mse: 0.1824 - mae: 0.1845 - val_loss: 46171.5547 - val_mse: 0.1824 - val_mae: 0.1845
Epoch 100/100
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 45709.4219 - mse: 0.1824 - mae: 0.1845 - val_loss: 47696.0117 - val_mse: 0.1824 - val_mae: 0.1845
```

What could I be doing wrong? I've tried adding and removing hidden layers to play with the complexity of the model, but nothing helps. Is it just not possible to train an autoencoder for a tabular dataset? The dataset is fairly big, (1460, 276), so why is the autoencoder underfitting?

Comment: ```batch_size=3000```, for starters, let `batch_size` be `32`.  Also, your output layer has an activation function. Think again, can that activation function freely reach minimum and maximum values in your data?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've changed the batch size´and changed the output layer's activation function to tanh. the network now trains really fast, in a matter of seconds and the loss is still really bad.

Comment: Does every feature in the dataset that you are trying to encode fall within [-1,1] range? `tanh` can only produce numbers within that range. If so, plot the loss over time and check that loss value converges. That's all I can recommend without seeing full code.

Comment: I normalized the data, so tanh should work fine. 
What code would you need? I can share it. The stuff i didn't share is just normalization, dummifying and train-test splitting the data.
A side question: Do I actually need to normalize the data when training autoencoders? Does that usually deliver better results?

Comment: You can make a copy of your notebook or script and share it on [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/). You do. Any GD algorithm needs normalization.  A vanishing gradient problem is solved by normalization. You can use higher learning rates with normalization. There is really no reason not to use it. Aside from laziness.

Comment: Here's the notebook link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NQQEd8KlZH441l2MCXPn16fwOYmuCaWT?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't have `house_prices/train.csv`. Could you also provide a link to that dataset?

Comment: Also, you are using `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize`. You really shouldn't do that unless you know what you are doing. It normalizes each row **independently**. See [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/scale-standardize-or-normalize-with-scikit-learn-6ccc7d176a02).

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data?select=train.csv
oh wow, i didn't know that. thanks, i'll read up on that